# What could be the solution to error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to call a document reference but I keep getting this error type

> 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

The relevant error-causing widget was `FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>.` What could be the issue?
[See Firebase Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV789.png)

```
CollectionReference productsRef = Firestore.instance.collection("MyShop");

FirebaseServices _firebaseServices = FirebaseServices();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder(  //          <<<<<===================FutureBuilder
          future: productsRef
              .document(widget.shopname)
              .collection("Cart")
              .where("myid", isEqualTo: widget.myid)
              .getDocuments(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              Text("Loading ..");
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 24.0,
                          left: 24.0,
                          right: 24.0,
                          bottom: 4.0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "${snapshot.data.documents["myname"]}", //   <<<=========Doceference
                          style: Constants.boldHeading,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it needs to use an integer for the documents like this

```
snapshot.data.documents[0].data['myname']
```

Comment: says [RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
]

Comment: try to console snapshot.data.documents and see the result